# Is it possible to get files from Dropbox and Google Drive files application in IOS sdk

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I'm developing an application in which the user can select his/her file from Dropbox or Google drive and download and share it to other users.

1. Can we check that is Google drive installed as we can check dropbox with help of below code :-

> if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL 
>          URLWithString:@"dbapi-1://"]])
>          {}

2. Once we know that the Dropbox and Google drive is installed. Can we get the files/folder from the installed application or Is it the standard process to check and then the dropbox list of files and display it manually with help of below code.

> if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]){
>                 [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
>             }

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest that you use [`UIDocumentMenuViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html) - This will allow the user to select a file from any supported cloud file provider; oneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, iCloud Drive etc, without you needing to write specific code for each one.

Comment: Very well, i will try it Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Paulw11 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867310/is-it-possible-to-get-files-from-dropbox-and-google-drive-files-application-in-i#comment76713860_44867310), if `UIDocumentMenuViewController` suits your needs, you can certainly use that.

Alternatively, Dropbox also offers [an API you can use to integrate Dropbox functionality into your app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). For Objective-C on iOS, you should use the [Dropbox API v2 Objective-C SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c).

There are [instructions for getting started](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#get-started) with that, as well as [samples for listing files and folders, etc.](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#rpc-style-request).

(Note that the code from your question is for the [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) [Dropbox API v1 iOS SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios). That should no longer be used since API v1 is being retired later this year.)